# How to achieve SQL "ON" functionality in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have the following query

```
select x from ProjTable
join GeneralAccEntry 
on (Projtable.ProjId= substr(GeneralAccEntry.fieldy), 25,7)
```

I created a form with `ProjTable` as main datasource. Now I want to add a calculated display field which shows the sum of `fieldY` from the related `GeneralAccEntry` table. I'm having difficulties retrieving the sum per `projId` because the method doesn't take `projId` as a parameter.

What's the correct way to create this display method?

Answer (score 0):

Just try with "WHERE" instead of "ON".

```
select x 
    from ProjTable 
    join GeneralAccEntry 
        WHERE Projtable.ProjId = substr(GeneralAccEntry.fieldy, 25,7)
```

Be careful with comparing using a function, it may give you an error. In case it does try to assign the result of the substr to a str variable with a defined length (like str 20 varName).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But would the following resolve your problem:

```
 Add method to your table ProjTable:

    public display real sumOfGeneralAccEntry() 
    {
        GeneralAccEntry generalAccEntry;
        str filter = '*' + this.ProjId + '*';

        select sum(fieldY)
        from generalAccEntry
        where generalAccEntry.fieldY like filter;


        return generalAccEntry.fieldY;
    }

Add the display to a field group

Add the fieldgroup into your form
```